# How do I use Pandas for reading multiple xlsx files and outputting into one in individual file in multiple sheets?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx, openpyxl

The `.xlsx` files are all found in one directory. There is only `.xlsx` file in this directory. I need to take each of the individual `.xlsx` files and insert it into a single sheet.

The example looks like this:

1. Directory has 4 `.xlsx` files
2. Read all 4 `.xlsx` files
3. Put all 4 `.xlsx` files into one single file
4. Each file should represent one sheet.

The final result should be one *Excel* file with 4 sheets.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question? Also provide the code you wrote so far and the error you're getting if any. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process for doing this is:

**0**. Setup

Install required packages:

```
pip install pandas
pip install xlsxwriter
```

Then import pandas into the Python file you're working in:

```
import pandas as pd
```

**1**. Read in the `.xlsx` files

*a*. Each by name:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('./excelfile1.xlsx')
```

etc

*b*. Read all in current directory in:

```
import os, re
dfs = []
for fname in os.listdir():
    if re.search(r'\.xlsx$', fname):
        dfs.append(pd.read_excel(fname))
```

**2**. Create a new file and add existing files as sheets

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('./newfilename.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
sheet_names = ['sheet1', ...]
for df, sheet_name in zip(dfs, sheet_names):
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)
writer.save()
```

This will create a new Excel file in the current directory called `newfilename.xlsx` with each of your existing Excel files as sheets.