# How to export dfs to excel with multiple sheets and different sheet names pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, loops

I am trying to iterate through student ID's WITH A LOOP by printing a df to a sheet in excel and having the student ID be the tab name.

In other words:

df to excel and tab name is 1

next df to new sheet and tab name is 2

iterate through all student IDs

```
final=[dataframe,dataframe,dataframe]
studentIDs=[1,2,3]


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Name.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for df in final:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='%s' %studentIDs)
    writer.save()
```

Comment: This might have the answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792576/how-do-i-use-pandas-for-reading-multiple-xlsx-files-and-outputting-into-one-in-i/51793105#51793105

Comment: @HenryWoody that’s also a very good implementation; using zip()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
final=[dataframe,dataframe,dataframe] 

studentIDs=[1,2,3]


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Name.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for i,df in enumerate(final, 0):
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='%s' %studentIDs[i])
     
writer.save()
```

If the lists will always match in order, then you can use enumerate (which gives you a list starting from that index onward) and then match it up to the list above, but I would recommend using a dictionary

```
final = {
   1 : dataframe,
   2 : dataframe,
   3 : dataframe
}


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Name.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for sheet_name in final:
    final[sheet_name].to_excel(writer, sheet_name= str(sheet_name))
    
writer.save()
```

Comment: This is perfect! I appreciate the help. I had this code already and it wasn't working because the 'writer.save()' was in the loop when I was running it and you have it outside the loop! Thank you!